# ¿Porque al crear un webview en python obtengo este error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy haciendo un webview simple que añadire a lado de un widgettable dentro mi programa en python, les muestro el codigo completo de mi programa:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView 
# Get Old Tweets
import GetOldTweets3 as got
# Hilos
from threading import Thread
import time
# ttk messagebox


class GroupBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 150, 600, 400))
        self.setWindowTitle("CODESUR")
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        # self.table_tweet = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()

        # primer grupo
        groupbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Buscar en twitter", checkable=False)
        self.layout.addWidget(groupbox)
        # segundo grupo
        groupbox_dos = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Progreso busqueda", checkable=False)
        self.layout.addWidget(groupbox_dos)
        # tercer grupo
        groupbox_tres = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Resultados busqueda", checkable=False)
        self.layout.addWidget(groupbox_tres)
        # self.layout.addWidget(self.table_tweet)

        # elementos del primer grupo
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        groupbox.setLayout(hbox)
        label_text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Buscar tweets")
        self.search_text = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.search_text.setMinimumSize(340, 15)
        self.search_text.setMaximumSize(350, 25)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Buscar en twitter")
        button.clicked.connect(self.mostrar_tabla)
        hbox.addWidget(label_text, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        hbox.addWidget(self.search_text, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        hbox.addWidget(button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        hbox.addStretch()
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(2, 1)

        # elementos del segundo grupo
        hbox_dos = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        groupbox_dos.setLayout(hbox_dos)
        label_title = QtWidgets.QLabel("Progreso de la busqueda")
        self.progressbar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        self.progressbar.setGeometry(200, 80, 250, 20)
        #self.progressbar.setMaximum(100)
        hbox_dos.addWidget(label_title, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        hbox_dos.addWidget(self.progressbar, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        hbox_dos.addStretch()
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(2,1)
        self.layout.setRowStretch(2,1)

        # elementos del tercer grupo
        hbox_tres = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        groupbox_tres.setLayout(hbox_tres)
        self.table_tweet = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.web_view = QWebEngineView()
        self.web_view.load(QUrl("https://twitter.com/"))
        hbox_tres.addWidget(self.table_tweet, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        hbox_tres.addWidget(self.web_view, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

    def mostrar_tabla(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self,"Busqueda iniciada","Los resultados se cargaran pronto")
        query_tweets = self.search_text.toPlainText()        

        count = 0

        tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch(query_tweets).setSince(
            "2018-05-01").setUntil("2019-05-01").setMaxTweets(100).setNear("Montevideo, Uruguay").setWithin("15mi")
        all_tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)

        self.progressbar.setMaximum(len(all_tweets))

        # crear el table widget
        #self.table_tweet = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.table_tweet.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)                
        self.table_tweet.setColumnCount(4)
        self.table_tweet.setRowCount(len(all_tweets))

        # inicializar el encabezado de las columnas
        header = self.table_tweet.horizontalHeader()
        self.table_tweet.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Fecha","Texto","Autor","Descripcion del perfil"])

        # inicializar los tooltips del encabezado
        self.table_tweet.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        self.table_tweet.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        self.table_tweet.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        self.table_tweet.horizontalHeaderItem(3)

        # inicializar la alineación de los encabezados
        self.table_tweet.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.table_tweet.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.table_tweet.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.table_tweet.horizontalHeaderItem(3).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # ajustamos el tamaño de las columnas al contenido
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(3, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        for tweet in all_tweets:            
            time.sleep(0.05)
            self.progressbar.setValue(count+1)
            date_time = tweet.date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
            self.table_tweet.setItem(count,0,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(date_time))
            self.table_tweet.setItem(count,1,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(tweet.text))
            self.table_tweet.setItem(count,2,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(tweet.username))
            self.table_tweet.setItem(count,3,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("https://twitter.com/"+tweet.username))
            count += 1        
        self.table_tweet.move(0, 0)

        #self.layout.addWidget(self.table_tweet)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = GroupBox()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Es en esta sección donde intento crear el webview:

```
        hbox_tres = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        groupbox_tres.setLayout(hbox_tres)
        self.table_tweet = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.web_view = QWebEngineView()
        self.web_view.load(QUrl("https://twitter.com/"))
        hbox_tres.addWidget(self.table_tweet, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        hbox_tres.addWidget(self.web_view, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
```

Pero al ejecutarlo obtengo este error:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

Intente instalar QtWebEngineWidgets usando el comando pip, pero despues de eso la ventana de mi programa se cierra despues de que la url se termina de cargar en el webview, he tratado de instalar una version anterior de PyQt5, pero no me deja instalara tambien acabo de actualizar la version de python que tengo instalada y no logro solucionar este error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebEngine se ha movido a un paquete aparte a partir de PyQt 5.12:

- https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/news/pyqt-512

Pero no debes intentar instalar `QtWebEngineWidgets`, el paquete (que contiene `QtWebEngineWidgets`, `QtWebEngine` y `QtWebEngineCore`) es [PyQtWebEngine](https://pypi.org/project/PyQtWebEngine/).

```
python -m pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

Comment: acabo de instalar PyQtWebEngine como me dijiste, pero ahora mi programa se cierra cuando termina de cargar la pagina dentro del webview